# Retrieve data from web site after 2 POST queries

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this [site](https://compare.energy.vic.gov.au/) to get the list of offers.
The problem is that we need to fill 2 forms (2 POST queries) before receiving the final result.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import requests as rs
from form_data import form_data1, form_data2
base_url = "https://compare.energy.vic.gov.au/api"
with rs.Session() as s:
   url_ = f"{base_url}/get-psb-details?serverCacheId=null"
   r = (s.get(url_))
   serverCacheId = r.json()["serverCacheId"]
   r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", data=form_data1)
   r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", data=form_data2)
```

Then I am trying to retrieve the offers after the second POST query:

```
url_ = "https://compare.energy.vic.gov.au/api/get-offers"
body = {"serverCacheId": str(serverCacheId),
  "loopBack": "false",
  "selectedEnergy": "/offer"}
r = s.get(url_, params=body)
print(r.json())
```

But unfortunately I get a message indicating a redirection:

```
{'status': 'redirect', 'message': 'no data'}
```

The 2 POSTs use the current data:

```
form_data1 = {
    "showSolarSelection": "true",
    "energyType": "Electricity",
    "userType": "Residential",
    "bill": "no bill",
    "postcode": "3000",
    "usageProfile": "0",
    "averageDailyConsumption": "0",
    "skipNMI": "true",
    "smartMeter": "1",
    "disclaimer": "true",
    "hasSolar": "0",
    "hasConcession": "0",
    "distributor": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Citipower",
        "display": "Citipower",
        "phone": "1300 301 101 / 13 12 80",
        "distribution_zone_id": "11",
        "distribution_zone_name": "All"
    },
    "distributorDerived": "0",
    "distributorSubmit": "true",
    "pageDataType": "energyConfigData",
    "loopBack": "true"
}
```

and

```
form_data2 = {
    "pvCapacity": "0", "pvCapacityCap": "null", "hhSize": "1", "totalRooms": "1", "fridgeCount": "0",
    "gasConnection": "4", "poolHeating": "0", "poolHeatingSolar": "false", "poolHeatingGas": "false",
    "poolHeatingElectric": "false", "poolHeatingNone": "false", "spaceHeatingElectricDucted": "false",
    "spaceHeatingSplitSystem": "false", "spaceHeatingElectricUnderfloor": "false",
    "spaceHeatingElectricIndividual": "false", "spaceHeatingGasDucted": "false",
    "spaceHeatingGasUnderfloor": "false", "spaceHeatingGasIndividual": "false", "spaceHeatingOther": "false",
    "spaceHeatingNone": "true", "spaceCoolingRoomAC": "false", "spaceCoolingSplitSystem": "false",
    "spaceCoolingDuctedReverse": "false", "spaceCoolingDuctedEvaporative": "false",
    "spaceCoolingPortableRef": "false", "spaceCoolingPortableEvap": "false", "spaceCoolingOther": "false",
    "spaceCoolingNone": "true", "seaDistance": "", "clothesDryer": "0", "clothesDryerWeekday": "",
    "clothesDryerWeekend": "", "dishwasherWeekday": "", "dishwasherWeekend": "",
    "waterHeatingElectric": "false", "waterHeatingElectricSolar": "false", "waterHeatingGasStorage": "false",
    "waterHeatingGasInstant": "false", "waterHeatingGasSolar": "false", "waterHeatingOther": "true",
    "controlledLoad": "", "tvTotal": "", "turnOffAtPowerShort": "", "ovensElectric": "", "ovensGas": "",
    "washingMachineUsage": "", "washingMachineWeekday": "", "washingMachineWeekend": "",
    "televisionUsageWeekday": "", "televisionUsageWeekend": "", "heatingUsageMethod": "",
    "gasUsageWinter": "0", "hhSize51": "", "energyType": "Electricity", "hasSolar": "0",
    "pageDataType": "energyProfileData", "loopBack": "false"
}
```

### Expected result

The expected result is a JSON object containing offers. Here is its structure:

```
{
  "selectedEnergyType": "Electricity",
  "energyTypeCount": 1,
  "offers": {
    "Electricity": {
      "offersList": [{...}]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site has some requirements and restrictions on the form data.

`form_data1`:

1. Add required fields `"solarCapacity"` and `"feedInTariff"`.

   ```py
   "hasSolar": "0",
   "solarCapacity": "",  # Add this
   "hasConcession": "0",
   "feedInTariff": "",   # Add this
   ```
2. Change `"loopBack": "true"` to `"loopBack": false`.

   ```py
   # "loopBack": "true"
   "loopBack": False
   ```
3. Set `"serverCacheId"` and change `data=` to `json=`.

   ```py
   # r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", data=form_data1)
   r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", json=dict(form_data1, serverCacheId=str(serverCacheId)))
   ```

`form_data2`:

1. Set `"serverCacheId"` and change `data=` to `json=`.

   ```py
   # r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", data=form_data2)
   r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", json=dict(form_data2, serverCacheId=str(serverCacheId)))
   ```
2. (Optional, for consistency) Change `"loopBack": "false"` to `"loopBack": false`.

   ```py
   # "loopBack": "false"
   "loopBack": False
   ```

---

The combined code:

```py
import requests as rs

form_data1 = {
    "showSolarSelection": "true",
    "energyType": "Electricity",
    "userType": "Residential",
    "bill": "no bill",
    "postcode": "3000",
    "usageProfile": "0",
    "averageDailyConsumption": "0",
    "skipNMI": "true",
    "smartMeter": "1",
    "disclaimer": "true",
    "hasSolar": "0",
    "solarCapacity": "",
    "hasConcession": "0",
    "feedInTariff": "",
    "distributor": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Citipower",
        "display": "Citipower",
        "phone": "1300 301 101 / 13 12 80",
        "distribution_zone_id": "11",
        "distribution_zone_name": "All"
    },
    "distributorDerived": "0",
    "distributorSubmit": "true",
    "pageDataType": "energyConfigData",
    "loopBack": False
}

form_data2 = {
    "pvCapacity": "0", "pvCapacityCap": "null", "hhSize": "1", "totalRooms": "1", "fridgeCount": "0",
    "gasConnection": "4", "poolHeating": "0", "poolHeatingSolar": "false", "poolHeatingGas": "false",
    "poolHeatingElectric": "false", "poolHeatingNone": "false", "spaceHeatingElectricDucted": "false",
    "spaceHeatingSplitSystem": "false", "spaceHeatingElectricUnderfloor": "false",
    "spaceHeatingElectricIndividual": "false", "spaceHeatingGasDucted": "false",
    "spaceHeatingGasUnderfloor": "false", "spaceHeatingGasIndividual": "false", "spaceHeatingOther": "false",
    "spaceHeatingNone": "true", "spaceCoolingRoomAC": "false", "spaceCoolingSplitSystem": "false",
    "spaceCoolingDuctedReverse": "false", "spaceCoolingDuctedEvaporative": "false",
    "spaceCoolingPortableRef": "false", "spaceCoolingPortableEvap": "false", "spaceCoolingOther": "false",
    "spaceCoolingNone": "true", "seaDistance": "", "clothesDryer": "0", "clothesDryerWeekday": "",
    "clothesDryerWeekend": "", "dishwasherWeekday": "", "dishwasherWeekend": "",
    "waterHeatingElectric": "false", "waterHeatingElectricSolar": "false", "waterHeatingGasStorage": "false",
    "waterHeatingGasInstant": "false", "waterHeatingGasSolar": "false", "waterHeatingOther": "true",
    "controlledLoad": "", "tvTotal": "", "turnOffAtPowerShort": "", "ovensElectric": "", "ovensGas": "",
    "washingMachineUsage": "", "washingMachineWeekday": "", "washingMachineWeekend": "",
    "televisionUsageWeekday": "", "televisionUsageWeekend": "", "heatingUsageMethod": "",
    "gasUsageWinter": "0", "hhSize51": "", "energyType": "Electricity", "hasSolar": "0",
    "pageDataType": "energyProfileData", "loopBack": False
}

base_url = "https://compare.energy.vic.gov.au/api"
with rs.Session() as s:
   url_ = f"{base_url}/get-psb-details?serverCacheId=null"
   r = (s.get(url_))
   serverCacheId = r.json()["serverCacheId"]
   r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", json=dict(form_data1, serverCacheId=str(serverCacheId)))
   r = s.post(f"{base_url}/save-form-data", json=dict(form_data2, serverCacheId=str(serverCacheId)))

url_ = "https://compare.energy.vic.gov.au/api/get-offers"
body = {"serverCacheId": str(serverCacheId),
  "loopBack": "false",
  "selectedEnergy": "/offer"}
r = s.get(url_, params=body)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: @agstudy Ok, added.